# Why "Array.prototype.slice(arguments)" gives me an empty "[]"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, arguments

I wrote a function `getMax` which simulates Math.max that could get the maximum number from a group of numbers. The function accepts variable arguments.

1. I use `Array.prototype.slice(arguments)` to turn them into a real array. But I failed, I get an empty array []. If I use `Array.from(arguments)` I will get a correct array. I don't know why traditional way of `Array.prototype.slice(arguments)` doesn't work for me.
2. Another problem with this function is that after I get a correct arguments array, the return value of `getMax` is `undefined`, but I do get a `return value 7` in `filterMax` function which confuses me a lot.

```js
function getMax() {
  "use strict";

  let filterMax = function(arr) {
    let maxValue = arr[0];
    let resultArr = arr.filter(function(value) {
      return value > maxValue;
    });
    if (resultArr.length == 0) {
      return maxValue; //output: 7
    } else {
      resultArr = filterMax(resultArr);
    }
  };

  let args = Array.from(arguments); //output: [ 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4 ]
  // let args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments);   //output: []

  console.log(args); //output: []

  return filterMax(args); //output: undefined
}

console.log(getMax(3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4)); //output: undefined
```

Comment: `[...arguments]` ?

Comment: I want to use traditional way Array.prototype.slice(arguments) here

Answer (score 1):

```
 Array.prototype.slice(arguments)
```

is basically the same as

```
 [].slice(arguments)
```

*(except that `this` is `Array.prototype` in the first case, but that is more or less equal to calling it on an empty array)*

... and that returns an empty array, because slicing from an empty array will always result in an empty array. You might wanted to do:

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

that calls `.slice` with `this` being `arguments`, thus it results in the wanted array, but I'd prefer `Array.from(arguments)` or `[...arguments]`, or even better, a rest parameter:

```
function findMax(...numbers) {
  //...
}
```

> Another problem with this function is that after I get a correct arguments array, the return value of getMax is undefined, but I do get a return value 7 in filterMax function which confuses me

Well, thats because:

```
let maxValue = arr[0];
let resultArr = arr.filter(function(value) {
  return value > maxValue;
});
```

filters out any array elements that are bigger than the first one (5 and 7 are bigger than 3 in your example), thus the code goes into the else branch ...

```
  resultArr = filterMax(resultArr);
```

... and returns *nothing* (aka `undefined`). You might want to

```
 return filterMax(resultArr);
```

All in all:

```js
function getMax(...numbers) {
  function filterMax(numbers) {
    const first = numbers[0];
    const bigger = numbers.filter(function(value) {
      return value > first;
    });
    
    if (bigger.length == 0) {
      return first;
    } else {
      return filterMax(bigger);
    }
  };



  return filterMax(numbers);
}

console.log(getMax(3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4)); //output: 7
```

Comment: _getMax which simulates Math.max_

Comment: @mplungjan ah, right, should've read the question before answering :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for your explanations, which helped me gain more understanding on recursion.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `call` to convert arguments to real array.
2. Secondly you are returning `filterMax` from `getMax` but you are returning anything from `filterMax`. You need to return `resultArr`

```js
function getMax() {
  "use strict";

  let filterMax = function(arr) {
    let maxValue = arr[0];
    let resultArr = arr.filter(function(value) {
      return value > maxValue;
    });
    if (resultArr.length == 0) {
      return maxValue; //output: 7
    } else {
      resultArr = filterMax(resultArr);
    }
    return resultArr;
  };

  //let args = Array.from(arguments); //output: [ 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4 ]
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);   //output: []

  console.log(args); //output: []

  return filterMax(args); //output: undefined
}

console.log(getMax(3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4)); //output: undefined
```

Comment: Thanks, @Maheer Ali, you are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `arguments` is an `Object`, not an `Array`. It works with `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`.

And you also forgot to return a value in your `filterMax()` function.

```js
function getMax() {
  "use strict";

  let filterMax = function(arr) {
    let maxValue = arr[0];
    let resultArr = arr.filter(function(value) {
      return value > maxValue;
    });
    if (resultArr.length == 0) {
      return maxValue; //output: 7
    } else {
      resultArr = filterMax(resultArr);
      // you forgot to return a value here
      return resultArr
    }
  };
  // Your arguments is an Object, not an array
  console.log('arguments:', arguments)
  // let args = Array.from(arguments); //output: [ 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4 ]
  // If you do it like this, it works:
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //output: []

  console.log(args); //output: []

  return filterMax(args); //output: undefined
}

console.log(getMax(3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 4)); //output: undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations,  I've learned a lot from them.